# D3.JS yScale returning "undefined" for only one single value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3.js for the first time, i used this code to draw a bar chart.

```
var dataset = [20, 55, 30, 40, 50, 35, 97, 75, 100, 45];
var w = 500;
var h =100;
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                .rangeRound([0,w])
                .paddingInner(0.05);

var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(d3.range(d3.max(dataset)))
                .rangeRound([0,h]);

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d,i) {
        return xScale(i);
    })
    .attr("y",function(d){console.log(yScale(d)); return h - yScale(d);})
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("fill", function(d) {if(d<50) { return "blue" }
            else if (d>=50) { return "red" }; })
    .attr("height", function(d){return yScale(d);
    });
```

But i'm getting this result:

[image: result]

I can't undersand why i'm getting "undefined" for one specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the yScale domain, and using d3.range to set the domain.

d3.range(100) creates an array with 100 elements, with values from 0 to 99. So when you try to get yScale(100), "100" is not in the domain.

For your data, you would recommend using a linear scale, for example

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
 .rangeRound([0,h]);
```

Or if you need to use d3.range, set the number of elements to 1 + the max value, for example:

```
var yScale = d3.scaleRange()
.domain(d3.range(d3.max(dataset) + 1))
.rangeRound([0,h]);
```